# Print dictionary values linked to keys which are in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So let's say I have a list of words:

```
listA = ['apple', 'bee', 'croissant']
```

and a dictionary:

```
dictA = {'bee': '100', 'apple': '200', 'croissant': '450'}
```

How do I get a print like this?

```
apple costs 200
bee costs 100
croissant costs 450
```

The problem here is the alphabetical order, it is the reason I need to get the values from the dictionary using the list. I hope the question is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a list for ordering your dict, you can just use `sorted` to sort by `key`,

```
dictA = {'bee': '100', 'apple': '200', 'croissant': '450'}

for key in sorted(dictA):
    print ("{} costs {}".format(key, dictA[key]))

# output,

apple costs 200
bee costs 100
croissant costs 450
```

or one liner,

```
print (sorted("{} costs {}".format(key, dictA[key]) for key in dictA))

#  output,
['apple costs 200', 'bee costs 100', 'croissant costs 450']
```

Comment: I read somewhere that dictionaries could not be sorted as themselves. However this clearly proves that to be false information. Many thanks, and have a great day!